# RealityKit – Specify a LiDAR scanning area

Tags: swift, arkit, metal, realitykit, lidar

I am currently developing an application that has the end goal of scanning furniture and creating an `.obj` file from it. As you can imagine when scanning using the scene reconstruction features in Swift, this produces a lot of noise for other objects that are around in the scan.

Is it possible to specify a scanning area which will work with my scanner and only take the object scanned within a certain square on screen ?